# export 'URL' (imported as 'URL') was not found in 'url' (possible exports: Url, format, parse, resolve, resolveObject)

Tags: javascript, webpack, puppeteer

i am trying to load the google map using google map api and webpack. In app.js imports runs without errors except the last:

```
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { Tween, Easing } from 'tween';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
```

When i begin i started using selenium-webdriver and i also get this mistakes ( about 127 ).

With ChatGPT help i decrease it to 3 errors and 13 warnings. Some of errors:

```
export 'urlToHttpOptions' (imported as 'urlToHttpOptions') was not found in 'url' (possible exports: Url, format, parse, resolve, resolveObject)

export 'URL' (imported as 'URL') was not found in 'url' (possible exports: Url, format, parse, resolve, resolveObject)

export 'fileURLToPath' (imported as 'fileURLToPath') was not found in 'url' (possible exports: Url, format, parse, resolve, resolveObject)


Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\messi\Desktop\Nay\maps-platform-101-webgl-main\starter\node_modules\raw-body'

Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Webpack.config.js looks:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs');

const CONFIG = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      fs: false,
      os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
      https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
      constants: require.resolve('constants-browserify'),
      zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      tls: require.resolve('tls-browserify'),
      net: require.resolve('net-browserify'),
      async_hooks: require.resolve('async_hooks'),
      querystring: require.resolve('querystring-es3'),
      child_process: false,
      readline: false,
      url: require.resolve('url').URL
        ? { ...require.resolve('url'), ...require.resolve('url').URL }
        : require.resolve('url'),
      dns: false,
      module: false,
      typescript: require.resolve('typescript'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      fs: 'graceful-fs',
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = CONFIG;
```

i spend some of time on these errors and understood that one of reason why these errors appear is different versions of dependencies, so there dependencies i've installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.16.2",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "async_hooks": "^1.0.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "easing-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11",
    "gsap": "^3.12.4",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "net-browserify": "^0.2.4",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "puppeteer": "^21.11.0",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.17.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "three": "^0.138.3",
    "tls-browserify": "^0.2.2",
    "tween": "^0.9.0",
    "tween.js": "^16.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. I hope decrease mistakes to zero and successfully load the map with some parsing dependency